# Framework7 v2 Calendar Instance

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I cannot clearly understand how Framework7 v2 instances work.

I create a calendar instance but although I don't destroy this instance when I change page to my app this calendar instance is not available.

This is how I create the instance:

```js
var calendar = app.calendar.create({
    inputEl: '#myCalendar'
});
```

An instance is available to a page scope only?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048585/framework7-inline-pages-components-initialize-not-firing/48064657#48064657 check this link